# Roslyn VB.Net Specify Compiler Version

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

I am trying to compile a VB program using the code below, the code requires VB 15.5 and even when I specify LanguageVersion.Latest or LanguageVersion.VisualBasic15_5, I still get error ERR_ExpectedNamedArgument - Named argument expected. Please use language version 15.5 or greater to use non-trailing named arguments. Some code was removed to simplify example.

```
    Public Function CompileVisualBasicString(StringToBeCompiler As String,  SeverityToReport As DiagnosticSeverity, ByRef ResultOfConversion As ConversionResult) As EmitResult
    If StringToBeCompiler.IsEmptyNullOrWhitespace Then
        ResultOfConversion.FilteredListOfFailures = New List(Of Diagnostic)
        ResultOfConversion.Success = True
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Dim syntaxTree As SyntaxTree = VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(StringToBeCompiler)
    Dim assemblyName As String = Path.GetRandomFileName()

    Dim PreprocessorSymbols As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
        {"NETSTANDARD2_0", Nothing}
    }

    Dim ParseOptions As VisualBasicParseOptions = New VisualBasicParseOptions(
            languageVersion:=LanguageVersion.Latest,
            documentationMode:=DocumentationMode.Diagnose,
            kind:=SourceCodeKind.Regular,
            preprocessorSymbols:=PreprocessorSymbols)

    Dim CompilationOptions As VisualBasicCompilationOptions = New VisualBasicCompilationOptions(
                                                                        outputKind:=OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary,
                                                                        optionExplicit:=False,
                                                                        optionInfer:=True,
                                                                        optionStrict:=OptionStrict.Off,
                                                                        parseOptions:=ParseOptions
                                                                        )
    Dim compilation As VisualBasicCompilation = VisualBasicCompilation.Create(
                                                                assemblyName:=assemblyName,
                                                                syntaxTrees:={syntaxTree},
                                                                references:=References,
                                                                options:=CompilationOptions
                                                                              )

    Dim CompileResult As EmitResult
    Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        CompileResult = compilation.Emit(ms)
    End Using
    Return CompileResult
End Function
```

Comment: Did you try to use `VisualBasicParseOptions` during to parse text?! `...=VisualBasicSyntaxTree.ParseText(StringToBeCompiler, New VisualBasicParseOptions(...))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you George, you solved the problem I needed to include the VisualBasicParseOption to Parse in addition to compile.